# Map entries higher than Integer.MAX_VALUE

Tags: java, chronicle-map

I am working with very large collections of small objects. I am using using `ChronicleMap` which is performing very well.

Is the maximum number of map entries limited to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`?

If not, how do I get the real size of a map as the `map.size()` returns `Integer.MAX_VALUE` if the number of entries is higher than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`ChronicleMap.longSize`](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map/blob/master/src/main/java/net/openhft/chronicle/map/VanillaChronicleMap.java#L196) instead to get the size as a `long`. [`ChronicleMap.size`](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map/blob/master/src/main/java/net/openhft/chronicle/hash/impl/VanillaChronicleHash.java#L707) will return `Integer.MAX_VALUE` when the size is greater then `Integer.MAX_VALUE` per the source: https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map/blob/master/src/main/java/net/openhft/chronicle/hash/impl/VanillaChronicleHash.java#L707

This is in accordance with the [`Collection.size`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#size--) interface:

> Returns the number of elements in this collection. If this collection
>   contains more than Integer.MAX_VALUE elements, returns
>   Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Answer (score 2):

ChronicleMap size isn't limited to integer.MAX_VALUE as traditional map. To get the size, you can use `longSize()` which return a long value